# setInterval callback with context

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I started to learn React framework, but actually i am looking on this code from main site and still can't understand it

```
 tick: function() {
    this.setState({secondsElapsed: this.state.secondsElapsed + 1});
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
```

If i pass `this.tick` to `setInterval`, then when the timer event is fired under hood and `this.tick` is called, it should be probably called in context of `window` object, right? If this is true, then the code in `tick` function should be wrong, because there is no `setState` function on `window` object.

[full code](http://facebook.github.io/react/index.html)

```
var Timer = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {secondsElapsed: 0};
  },
  tick: function() {
    this.setState({secondsElapsed: this.state.secondsElapsed + 1});
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  },
  render: function() {
    return React.DOM.div({},
      'Seconds Elapsed: ', this.state.secondsElapsed
    );
  }
});

React.renderComponent(Timer({}), mountNode);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React autobinds methods defined in the component spec since that's almost always what you want. See this blog post for more details: [New in React v0.4: Autobind by Default](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2013/07/02/react-v0-4-autobind-by-default.html).

Comment: Weird.  While convenient in cases like the `setInterval()` example, that isn't the normal form of method invocation so it seems like it creates an extra function call overhead on EVERY method invocation as it attempts to reattach the proper `this` again even if it's already attached.  I don't think I want my framework redefining javascript basics like this.

Comment: I agree this is a little weird. It turns out that practically all methods that you're likely to define are event handlers or other methods like this example where the function is executed in the global context by default. I'm personally a little torn on this behavior, but I love almost all of the rest of React -- I encourage you to check it out if you haven't already.